# Use Multiple Computers as One SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, grid-computing

We have many computers and I am researching about using them like grid systems ? is that possible and effective?

Comment: Look at this: [SQL Server Failover Cluster Installation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231721.aspx)

Comment: Thanks @HamletHakobyan
For opening the situation ; My firm was started 6 years ago and jobs was a little count time by time they had to add new computer and seperated some job and db to it. again and again. Now I am started and View is MESS..
Failover Cluster seems supported in 2012 version of SQL Server. I think this may be the solution. First i want to test it in some virtual machines... Is that possible or did you practice this ?
Thnks for your time and experience.
Gamze

Comment: Ps. And Asp.net C# SQL Server is not my choice :( They have it. 
Also i am good at open systems :( Linux, MySQL, Oracle Ext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server Has something called Federated databases:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187467(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Thanks For the performans Federated Database solution seems very good. But the problem is we have to change our DB layer to work with it...

Comment: For Opening the situation,
There is 5 data suppliers updating many data table
3 services handling them and operating on data to make them usable on our software
2 web sites publishing this production data
2 Desktop Applications using production data after web users worked on it. And this menas extra tables and compare data from different instances of SQL on different computers :(
Comuters are mostly i5 with 8GB Ram :)